# MySQL - Bucle sobre un SELECT para hacer calculos y mostrar datos con condiciones

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, condiciones, bucles

Tengo dos tablas, pedido y productos.

La tabla pedido es esta...

[image: Tabla pedido]

Y la tabla productos es esta otra...

[image: Tabla productos]

Mi intencion es crear un procedure que haga lo siguiente:

1. Le paso una "idPedido" (pueden ser varios registros)
2. Hace un Select de todos los registros con esa "idPedido" e inicia un bucle
3. En dos variables llamadas "totalVenta" y "beneficio" va sumando...

   ```
   if(tieneDescuento){
      beneficio   += (precioConDescuento - precioCoste)
      totalVenta  +=  precioConDescuento
   }else{
      beneficio   += (precioSinDescuento - precioCoste)
      totalVenta  +=  precioSinDescuento
   }
   ```
4. En otra variable va sumando el total de artículos, que se va incrementando en función del valor de "cantidad" que haya en cada registro.
5. Finalmente, y no se si esto es posible (bueno, ni lo otro tampoco), quisiera crear una vista en la que, en una sola línea, muestre algo así

   ```
        idPedido      totalArticulos      totalVenta      beneficio
         asd123            36               10564           2954
   ```

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo he conseguido. Por si a alguien le sirve en un futuro, ahí va!

```
/* Mostrar cifras de un pedido */
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS muestraPedido;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE muestraPedido(IN idPed INT(10))
BEGIN

    DECLARE totalVenta INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE totalBeneficio INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE totalArticulos INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cant INT;
    DECLARE tieneDto INT;
    DECLARE pCoste INT;
    DECLARE pConDto INT;
    DECLARE pSinDto INT;

    /*Declaro el cursor para la busqueda */
    DECLARE pedidoCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT pe.cantidad, pe.tieneDescuento, pr.precioCoste, pr.precioCondescuento, pr.precioSinDescuento 
        FROM pedidos pe, productos pr 
        WHERE pe.idPedido = idPed AND pe.idProducto = pr.referencia;

    /*Declaro un manejador de error tipo NOT FOUND*/
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @hecho = true;

    /*Abro el cursor*/
    OPEN pedidoCursor;

    /*Empiezo el bucle de lectura*/
    loop1: LOOP
        /* Asigno la primera linea a las variables... */
        FETCH pedidoCursor INTO cant, tieneDto, pCoste, pConDto, pSinDto;

        IF tieneDto THEN
            SET totalBeneficio = totalBeneficio + ((pConDto - pCoste) * cant);
            SET totalVenta = totalVenta + (pConDto * cant);
        ELSE
            SET totalBeneficio = totalBeneficio + ((pSinDto - pCoste) * cant);
            SET totalVenta = totalVenta + (pSinDto * cant);
        END IF;

        SET totalArticulos = totalArticulos + cant;

        IF @hecho THEN
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;

        SET cant = 0;

    END LOOP loop1;
    CLOSE pedidoCursor;

    SELECT idPed AS Pedido, totalArticulos as 'Total Artículos', totalVenta AS 'Total Venta', totalBeneficio AS 'Total Beneficio';
END;
```

//

Finalmente, el resultado es el siguiente....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]